# Ограничения в использовании продукта с лицензией Apache 2.0

Tags: apache, лицензирование, авторские-права, юридические-аспекты

Каковы ограничения, если я применяю при разработке своего программного продукта чей-то код/библиотеку или SDK, которые поставляются авторами под лицензией Apache 2.0? А в частности - я имею право закрывать свои исходники от общественности, а также распространять свой программный продукт платно? Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_Apache

Данная лицензия не ставит условием неизменность лицензии распространения программного обеспечения, и не настаивает даже на сохранении его бесплатного и открытого статуса. Единственным условием, накладываемым лицензией Apache, является информирование получателя о факте использования исходного кода. Таким образом, в противоположность copyleft-лицензиям, получатель модифицированной версии не обязательно получает все права, изначально предоставляемые лицензией Apache.

При распространении программного обеспечения необходимо поместить следующие файлы в корневую директорию:

```
LICENSE — файл, содержащий копию текста лицензии Apache;
NOTICE — текстовый файл, перечисляющий все библиотеки, лицензированные под лицензией Apache вместе с именами их создателей.
```

В каждом лицензируемом файле должна быть сохранена вся исходная информация о копирайтах или патентах, в каждый изменённый файл должна добавляться информация о проведённых изменениях.

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html

You may add Your own copyright statement to Your modifications and may provide additional or different license terms and conditions for use, reproduction, or distribution of Your modifications, or for any such Derivative Works as a whole, provided Your use, reproduction, and distribution of the Work otherwise complies with the conditions stated in this License.

---

что  именно из этого не понятно ?